# Wrong syntax in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have some mistakes which I don't know how to solve.  When I execute this stored procedure, I have these mistakes:

```
Mens. 102, Level 15, state 1, Line 13
wrong syntax near of ')'.
Mens. 137, Level 15, state 2, Line 13
Must declare the scalar variable "@n".
Mens. 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 431
wrong syntax near of 'P'.
```

Where is the mistake? This is the code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PA_InformeOperacionesUSD_MX]
        @trimestre INT,
        @anio INT
AS
BEGIN


DECLARE @filtro TABLE (IdPais INT,IdCentro INT,BaseDato NVARCHAR(50),ISOALocal CHAR(3), ClaveSucursal NVARCHAR(8))
DECLARE @tipooperacion INT,
        @insrtumentomonetario INT,
        @instrumentomonetarioliquidacion INT,
        @colonia NVARCHAR(4),
        @isoalocal CHAR(3),
        @anio2 INT,
        @isoaofrece CHAR(3),
        @centro INT,
        @sql NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @basedato NVARCHAR(50),
        @clavesucursal NVARCHAR(50),
        @max DECIMAL(24,10),
        @trim1 NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @n INT


INSERT INTO @filtro (IdPais, IdCentro,BaseDato,ISOALocal,ClaveSucursal)
            SELECT DISTINCT CodigoPais, IdCentro, BaseDatoGCH2010,CodigoISOA, ClaveSucursal
            FROM Centro C
            INNER JOIN Pais P ON C.Codigopais=P.Idpais 
            WHERE Productivo=1
            AND BaseDatoGCH2010 IS NOT NULL
            AND CodigoPais=105
WHILE EXISTS (Select * from @filtro)
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 @centro=Idcentro,
                @basedato=BaseDato,
                @isoalocal=ISOALocal,
                @clavesucursal=ClaveSucursal 
    FROM @filtro
    IF SERVERPROPERTY('MachineName')='VENUS' 
    BEGIN
        SET @basedato='MARTE.'+@basedato
    END
    IF SERVERPROPERTY('MachineName')='MELIBEA' 
    BEGIN
        SET @basedato='PANDORA.'+@basedato
    END
    IF SERVERPROPERTY('MachineName') = 'SRVDES01'
    BEGIN
        SET @basedato = 'SRVDES03.'+@basedato   
    END     
    SET @sql=ISNULL(@sql+' UNION ', '')+N'SELECT 
                                             FechaHora=CONVERT(NVARCHAR,O.Fecha,112)+''''+REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR,O.Fecha,108),'':'',''''),
                                             TipoOperacion=@tipooperacion,
                                             Recibo=Convert(NVARCHAR,O.Recibo),
                                             O.Ofrece,
                                             O.CodigoISOAOfrece,
                                             InstrumentoMonetario=@insrtumentomonetario,
                                             CuentaContratoLiquidacion=O.Recibo,
                                             O.Demanda,
                                             MonedaLiquidacion=@isoalocal,
                                             InstrumentoMonetarioLiquidacion=@instrumentomonetarioliquidacion,
                                             Sucursal='''+@clavesucursal+''',
                                             Nombre= CASE WHEN C.Nombre=''''THEN ''XXXX''
                                                    ELSE UPPER(ISNULL(dbo.F_SinCaracteresNoBCRA(C.Nombre),''XXXX'')) END,
                                             Apellido1= CASE WHEN C.Apellido1 ='''' THEN ''XXXX''
                                                        ELSE UPPER(ISNULL(dbo.F_SinCaracteresNoBCRA(C.Apellido1),''XXXX'')) END,
                                             Apellido2= UPPER(ISNULL(dbo.F_SinCaracteresNoBCRA(C.Apellido2),''XXXX'')),
                                             FechaNacimiento= CONVERT(NVARCHAR,C.FechaNacimiento,112),
                                             RFC= CASE WHEN C.CodigoPaisNacionalidad=''MX'' THEN ''XAXX010101000'' ELSE ''XEXX010101000'' END,
                                             CodigoPaisNacionalidad=CASE WHEN C.CodigoPaisNacionalidad IN (SELECT CodigoPais FROM PaisEquivalenteMX) THEN PQ.CodigoPaisEquivalente ELSE C.CodigoPaisNacionalidad END,
                                             Domicilio=UPPER(dbo.F_CambiaCaracteres(C.Direccion)+'' ''+ISNULL(dbo.F_CambiaCaracteres(C.Numero),'''')+'' ''+ISNULL(dbo.F_CambiaCaracteres(C.Piso),'''')+'' ''+ISNULL(dbo.F_CambiaCaracteres(C.Puerta),'''')+'' ''+dbo.F_CambiaCaracteres(C.Localidad)+'' ''+dbo.F_CambiaCaracteres(C.CodigoPostal)+'' ''+dbo.F_CambiaCaracteres(P.Pais)),
                                             Ciudad=UPPER(dbo.F_CambiaCaracteres(C.Localidad)),
                                             Colonia=@colonia,
                                             Documento=NULL,
                                             Pais=CASE WHEN C.CodigoPaisResidencia=''MX''THEN NULL 
                                                        WHEN C.CodigoPaisResidencia IN (SELECT CodigoPais FROM PaisEquivalenteMX) THEN PE.CodigoPaisEquivalente
                                                        ELSE C.CodigoPaisResidencia END 
                                    FROM '+@basedato+'.dbo.Operacion O
                                        INNER JOIN '+@basedato+'.dbo.Cliente C ON C.IdCliente=O.CodigoCliente
                                        INNER JOIN '+@basedato+'.dbo.Pais P ON P.IdPais=C.CodigoPaisResidencia
                                        LEFT JOIN PaisEquivalenteMX PE ON PE.CodigoPais=C.CodigoPaisResidencia
                                        LEFT JOIN PaisEquivalenteMX PQ ON PQ.CodigoPais=C.CodigoPaisNacionalidad         
                                    WHERE ((@trimestre=1 AND O.Fecha BETWEEN ''01/01/''+convert(nvarchar(4),@anio) AND ''01/04/''+convert(nvarchar(4),@anio)) 
                                            OR (@trimestre=2 AND O.Fecha BETWEEN ''01/04/''+convert(nvarchar(4),@anio) AND ''01/07/''+convert(nvarchar(4),@anio))
                                            OR (@trimestre=3 AND O.Fecha BETWEEN ''01/07/''+convert(nvarchar(4),@anio) AND ''01/10/''+convert(nvarchar(4),@anio))
                                            OR (@trimestre=4 AND O.Fecha BETWEEN ''01/10/''+convert(nvarchar(4),@anio) AND ''01/01/''+convert(nvarchar(4),@anio2)))
                                        AND O.CodigoISOADemanda=@isoalocal
                                        AND O.CodigoISOAOfrece=@isoaofrece
                                        AND O.Ofrece>@max'

    DELETE FROM @filtro Where IdCentro=@centro


        BEGIN

 IF @trimestre=2 
  BEGIN
    SET @trim1=N'SELECT @n=COUNT(O.Ofrece) FROM '+@basedato+'.dbo.Operacion O
                                        INNER JOIN '+@basedato+'.dbo.Cliente C ON C.IdCliente=O.CodigoCliente
                                        INNER JOIN '+@basedato+'.dbo.Pais P ON P.IdPais=C.CodigoPaisResidencia
                                        LEFT JOIN PaisEquivalenteMX PE ON PE.CodigoPais=C.CodigoPaisResidencia
                                        LEFT JOIN PaisEquivalenteMX PQ ON PQ.CodigoPais=C.CodigoPaisNacionalidad         
                                    WHERE ((O.Fecha BETWEEN ''01/01/''+convert(nvarchar(4),@anio) AND ''01/04/''+convert(nvarchar(4),@anio))) 
                                        AND O.CodigoISOADemanda=@isoalocal
                                        AND O.CodigoISOAOfrece=@isoaofrece
                                        AND O.Ofrece>@max'
                                        print @trim1
  END
  IF @trimestre=3
  BEGIN
    SET @trim1=N'SELECT @n=COUNT(O.Ofrece) FROM '+@basedato+'.dbo.Operacion O
                                        INNER JOIN '+@basedato+'.dbo.Cliente C ON C.IdCliente=O.CodigoCliente
                                        INNER JOIN '+@basedato+'.dbo.Pais P ON P.IdPais=C.CodigoPaisResidencia
                                        LEFT JOIN PaisEquivalenteMX PE ON PE.CodigoPais=C.CodigoPaisResidencia
                                        LEFT JOIN PaisEquivalenteMX PQ ON PQ.CodigoPais=C.CodigoPaisNacionalidad         
                                    WHERE ((O.Fecha BETWEEN ''01/01/''+convert(nvarchar(4),@anio) AND ''01/04/''+convert(nvarchar(4),@anio)) 
                                            OR (O.Fecha BETWEEN ''01/04/''+convert(nvarchar(4),@anio) AND ''01/07/''+convert(nvarchar(4),@anio)))
                                            OR O.CodigoISOADemanda=@isoalocal
                                        AND O.CodigoISOAOfrece=@isoaofrece
                                        AND O.Ofrece>@max'
                                        print @trim1
  END
  IF @trimestre=4
  BEGIN
    SET @trim1=N'SELECT @n=COUNT(O.Ofrece) FROM '+@basedato+'.dbo.Operacion O
                                        INNER JOIN '+@basedato+'.dbo.Cliente C ON C.IdCliente=O.CodigoCliente
                                        INNER JOIN '+@basedato+'.dbo.Pais P ON P.IdPais=C.CodigoPaisResidencia
                                        LEFT JOIN PaisEquivalenteMX PE ON PE.CodigoPais=C.CodigoPaisResidencia
                                        LEFT JOIN PaisEquivalenteMX PQ ON PQ.CodigoPais=C.CodigoPaisNacionalidad         
                                    WHERE ((O.Fecha BETWEEN ''01/01/''+convert(nvarchar(4),@anio) AND ''01/04/''+convert(nvarchar(4),@anio)) 
                                            OR (O.Fecha BETWEEN ''01/04/''+convert(nvarchar(4),@anio) AND ''01/07/''+convert(nvarchar(4),@anio))
                                            OR(O.Fecha BETWEEN ''01/07/''+convert(nvarchar(4),@anio) AND ''01/10/''+convert(nvarchar(4),@anio)))
                                            OR O.CodigoISOADemanda=@isoalocal
                                        AND O.CodigoISOAOfrece=@isoaofrece
                                        AND O.Ofrece>@max'
  END


  EXEC sp_executesql @trim1,N'@anio INT,                                
                            @isoalocal CHAR(3),
                            @anio2 INT,
                            @isoaofrece CHAR(3),
                            @max DECIMAL(24,10),
                            @n INT OUT',
                            @anio,                              
                            @isoalocal,
                            @anio2,
                            @isoaofrece,
                            @max,
                            @n OUT


END


END


SET @sql=N' SELECT FolioConsecutivo='''+convert(nvarchar,@anio)+'''+''-''+convert(nvarchar,(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Order by @anio)+@n)),* from ('+@sql+')P '


print @sql
EXEC sp_executesql @sql,N'@anio INT,
                            @tipooperacion INT,
                            @insrtumentomonetario INT,
                            @instrumentomonetarioliquidacion INT,
                            @colonia NVARCHAR(4),
                            @isoalocal CHAR(3),
                            @anio2 INT,
                            @trimestre INT,
                            @isoaofrece CHAR(3),
                            @centro INT,
                            @clavesucursal NVARCHAR(50),
                            @max DECIMAL(24,10),
                            @n',                                
                            @anio,
                            @tipooperacion,
                            @insrtumentomonetario,
                            @instrumentomonetarioliquidacion,
                            @colonia,
                            @isoalocal,
                            @anio2,
                            @trimestre,
                            @isoaofrece,
                            @centro,
                            @clavesucursal,
                            @max,
                            @n
END
```

One of the lines where I have problems is this SET @sql=N' SELECT FolioConsecutivo='''+convert(nvarchar,@anio)+'''+''-''+convert(nvarchar,(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Order by @anio)+@n)),* from ('+@sql+')P '
 because of the @n . I have declared it as INT as you can see it and then I want to convert it to nvarchar but. I have a mistake here. I try to find the mistake but I don't know.Please, could you help me?.
Thanks so much!

Comment: Way too much code for a question.

Comment: You can't expect us to solve your problems just by posting all your code. Describe the problem specifically and only post the code that is relevant please.

Comment: Either SQLServer's quality control has gone way down, or you're not posting the real error messages. "sintax" is not the proper spelling of "syntax", and "near of 'P'" is  not proper grammar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have one block of code that looks like this:

```
  EXEC sp_executesql @trim1,N'@anio INT,                                
                            @isoalocal CHAR(3),
                            @anio2 INT,
                            @isoaofrece CHAR(3),
                            @max DECIMAL(24,10),
                            @n INT OUT',
                            @anio,                              
                            @isoalocal,
                            @anio2,
                            @isoaofrece,
                            @max,
                            @n OUT
```

And another that looks like this:

```
EXEC sp_executesql @sql,N'@anio INT,
                            @tipooperacion INT,
                            @insrtumentomonetario INT,
                            @instrumentomonetarioliquidacion INT,
                            @colonia NVARCHAR(4),
                            @isoalocal CHAR(3),
                            @anio2 INT,
                            @trimestre INT,
                            @isoaofrece CHAR(3),
                            @centro INT,
                            @clavesucursal NVARCHAR(50),
                            @max DECIMAL(24,10),
                            @n',                                
                            @anio,
                            @tipooperacion,
                            @insrtumentomonetario,
                            @instrumentomonetarioliquidacion,
                            @colonia,
                            @isoalocal,
                            @anio2,
                            @trimestre,
                            @isoaofrece,
                            @centro,
                            @clavesucursal,
                            @max,
                            @n
```

In the first one, you're specifying "@n INT OUT", and in the second one you're not.  The second one is probably wrong.  That's at least one of your problems.

Comment: Thanks so much Johnny Bones, you are soooo great.